# Fermat's little theorem in JS

Tags: javascript, algebra

I just tried to implement Fermat's little theorem in JavaScript. I tried it both ways, a^(p-1) mod p = 1 and a^p mod p = a mod p.

```
function fermat(a, p) {
  return (((a ^ (p - 1)) % p) === 1);
}
```

and

```
function fermat(a, p) {
  return ( ( a^p ) % p ) === ( a % p );
}
```

It doesn't work both ways, is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Javascript `^` means [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). For [exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#In_programming_languages) you need `Math.pow(x, y)`.

```
function fermat(a, p) {
  return Math.pow(a, p - 1) % p === 1;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of ^, you need to use Math.pow

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the ^ vs. Math.pow() issue others have pointed out, the next hurdle
you will likely face is the limited precision of the Javascript built-in numeric
types.  You will very quickly exceed the range of exactly representable Javascript
numbers once the exponents start getting large, as they will be if you're wanting
to use a routine like this as a primality test.  You may want to look into
a Javascript bignum library (for example, [this one](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber)) that supports exponentiation
and modulus for arbitrarily large integers.

Comment: yes, I know that. I already implemented Fermat's little theorem in Java and got an extremely fast response, but when I tried to get all primes up to 10k, I ran out of limits. But this is just for a test on jsperf (http://jsperf.com/prime-numbers/4), and it performs nearly as fast as some solutions using a cache (for half a million operation-loops). I'm fine with that result…

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, the carat (^) is the XOR operator.  What you want to use is the Math.pow(x,y) function which is equivalent to x^y.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code (JavaScript) for checking whether a number is prime based on Fermat Little Theorem.

```
    function getRandomInt(min,max) { /* getting a random between given max and min values */
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.ceil(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;
    }

    function getGCD(a,b) { /* getting the greatest common divisor */
        var tmp;
        while (b !== 0) {
            tmp = b;
            b = a%b;
            a = tmp;
        }
        return a;
    }

    function getPower(a,b,p) { /* getting the a^b mod p */
        if (b == 1)
         return a%p;
        else {
         x = getPower(a,Math.floor(b/2),p);
         if (b%2 == 0) 
          return (x*x)%p;
         else return (((x*x)%p)*a)%p;
        }
    }

    function fermatTesting(Num) { //Checking Num by using Fermat's theorem
        var a = getRandomInt(2,Num-1);
        if (getGCD(a,Num) !== 1) {
            return "COMPOSITE";
        }
        else {
            if (getPower(a,Num-1,Num) !== 1) {
                return "COMPOSITE";
            }
            else {
                return "PRIME"; 
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(fermatTesting(57)); //Displays "COMPOSITE"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like answering an eleven year old question!

Since it's now 2021 we have support for [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), which supports arbitrary precision along with the exponentiation operator (`**`) and the modulus operator(`%`).

The function in the accepted answer can be rewritten as

```
function fermat(a, p) {
    return (a**(p-1n) % p) === 1n;
}
```

where `a` and `p` are BigInt values.